# Can a Python class be written such that it may be passed to write()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, byte

I'd like to pass an instance of my class to write() and have it written to a file. The underlying data is simply a bytearray.

```
mine = MyClass()

with open('Test.txt', 'wb') as f:

    f.write(mine)
```

I tried implementing `__bytes__` to no avail. I'm aware of the buffer protocol but I believe it can only be implemented via the C API (though I did see talk of delegation to an underlying object that implemented the protocol).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't, there are no special methods you can implement that'll make your Python class support the buffer protocol.

Yes, the [`io.RawIOBase.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write) and [`io.BufferedIOBase.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.write) methods document that they accept a [`bytes`-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object), but the buffer protocol needed to *make* something *`bytes`-like* [is a C-level protocol only](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects). There is an [open Python issue to add Python hooks](https://bugs.python.org/issue13797) but no progress has been made on this.

The [`__bytes__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bytes__) is only called if you passed an object to the `bytes()` callable; `.write()` does not do this.

So, when writing to a file, only actual `bytes`-like objects are accepted, *everything else* must be converted to such an object first. I'd stick with:

```
with open('Test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(mine))
```

which will call the `MyClass.__bytes__()` method, provided it is defined, or provide a method on your class that causes it to write itself to a file object:

```
with open('Test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    mine.dump(f)
```

Comment: Thanks. Excellent details.